# How to specify multiple binding files in gradle for ant xjc task

Tags: ant, gradle, xjc

I have  multiple bindings(xjb files) in the gradle project. When generating JAXB classes for a xsd(C.xsd). I want to use the previously generated binding files for A.xjb & B.xjb since C.xsd refers to A.xsd & B.xsd

The below ant xjc task works if I don't have anyother bindings in same path but I want specify explicity A.xjb & B.xjb bindings. How to go about same, I tried various options but nothing seems working. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
ant.xjc(destdir : '${jaxbDest}', removeOldOutput:'yes', extension:'true') {
  arg(line:'-Xequals -XhashCode -XtoString -Xcopyable')

  schema(dir:'src/main/schema', includes:'C.xsd')
  binding(dir:'src/main/schema', includes:'*.xjb)
```

}

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ea/docs/xjcTask.html) for the ant xjc task -

> "To specify more than one external binding file at the same time, use a nested  element, which has the same syntax as fileset."

In gradle it would look like this:

```
 binding(dir:'src/main/schema'){
    include(name:'A.xjb')
    include(name:'B.xjb')
 }
```

I think this would also work:

```
binding(dir:'src/main/schema', includes:'A.xjb,B.xjb')
```