# Multiple binding files in gradle xjc task

Tags: java, gradle, ant, jaxb, xjc

I want to specify a few files binding files in gradle task.

[I've read doc.](https://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ea/docs/xjcTask.html)

[Also I've checked this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946818/how-to-specify-multiple-binding-files-in-gradle-for-ant-xjc-task)

So, all works in such way:

```
          xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema, binding: 'src/main/resources/A.xjb')
```

And **not** works in such way:

```
   xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema, binding: binding(dir:'src/main/resources', includes:'A.xjb,B.xjb')      or
   xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema, binding(dir:'src/main/resources', includes:'A.xjb,B.xjb')
```

[Logs](https://pastebin.com/raw/LeXs7ExM)

Comment: That SO link that you provide seems to provide the answer. Did you try to implement what was suggested in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
    binding(dir:'src/main/resources', includes:'A.xjb,B.xjb')
}
```